# Installing the dependencies of local modules without composer merge plugin

Tags: 9, composer

Currently I have a composer-based Drupal project with both third-party and custom modules. Third-party modules are managed by composer without any issues. But I would like my *custom* modules to declare their dependencies in a `composer.json` within their directories, and also have them install when I run `composer install` at the root of the project.

```
composer.json
web/
  modules/
    contrib/
      address/  
      admin_toolbar/
      ...
    custom/
      my_module/
        composer.json
        ...
      my_other_module/
        composer.json
```

Currently:

- I have the [composer merge plugin](https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin) which works fine for the most part but would like to avoid using it. It has [a nasty habit of calling `update`](https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin/issues/218) and bumping dependency versions when it shouldn't.
- I've already looked into [Composer path repositories](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path). While it does install the dependencies of my custom modules, it also symlinks/copies my custom module into `web/modules/contrib` which is unnecessary because the custom modules are already in the right place in `web/modules/custom`.

In the future, I would splinter off these custom modules into their own projects and stored in their own repositories. But for now, they're still housed in the same project as the Drupal site I'm building.

How do I install dependencies declared in the `composer.json` of my local custom modules together with everything else?

Comment: I created the Vendor Stream Wrapper module to solve the issue I'm guessing you are probably trying to deal with. Maybe it can help you: https://www.drupal.org/project/vendor_stream_wrapper

Comment: If you set the `type` of your custom modules' composer.json files to `drupal-custom-module`, and you have a setting in your main composer.json under `installer-paths` for `type:drupal-custom-module` to go to `docroot/modules/custom/{$name}` (recent versions of the core recommended project already have this), the composer path repositories method _might_ work? Hopefully it's smart enough not to try to overwrite the source with itself

Answer (score 1):

This what I have to make it work:

web/modules/custom/my_custom/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "[provider]/my_custom",
    "type": "drupal-custom-module",
    "description": "My Custom Module.",
    "require": {
        "drupal/core": "^8.9 || ^9",
        "drupal/devel": "^2.1"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url":  "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        }
    ]
}
```

composer.json

```
{
...
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "web/modules/custom/my_custom"
    }
  ],
...
  "require": {
    ...
    "[provider]/my_custom": "*"
    ...
  },
  "extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
      ...
      "web/modules/custom/{$name}":   ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
      ...
    },
  }
...
}
```